# On stopping and restarting my application, I receive an address already in use error for JMX

Tags: java, bash, gradle, jmx, restart

I'm writing a script to stop and restart my service.  Ideally, it will be called by the JVM options, set in my gradle.build file, in the event of an out of memory error.  So far, it has been called and successfully killed the process, but when it calls the start script, I receive an error that says that the JMX port I also have set in my build file is already in use:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9010; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
sun.management.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9010; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:480)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9010; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:346)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:213)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:173)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:816)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:468)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

This does not make any sense to me, as I assume killing the service should also free up the port.

Here are my JVM options:

```
task appStartScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    def tplName = 'startTemplate.sh'
    assert project.file(tplName).exists()
    defaultJvmOpts = ["-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError",
                      "-XX:HeapDumpPath=\$HOME/log/",
                      "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
                      "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010",
                      "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
                      "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
                      "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=testHost",
                      "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./restart.sh",
                      "-Xms64m", "-Xmx124m"]
    dependsOn shadowJar
    applicationName = 'start'
    defaultJvmOpts += ["-Dspring.profiles.active=development"]
    classpath = startShadowScripts.classpath
    mainClassName = startShadowScripts.mainClassName
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'scriptsShadow')

    doLast {
        // IMPORTANT! needed to ensure HOME environment variable is expanded correctly
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('\\$HOME', '\'"$HOME"\'')
}
```

And here is my restart script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

envDeploy=`whoami`

if [ "$envDeploy" == "dev_account" ]; then
    envName=development
elif [ "$envDeploy" == "dev_account" ]
then
    envName=quality
elif [ "$envDeploy" == "prod_account" ]
then
    envName=production
fi

PID=`pgrep -f application.jar`

kill -9 $PID
sleep 15
echo "Restarting application for \$envName environment"
./start.sh $envName;
```

In theory, the service should be completely killed before calling start.sh, so I'm a bit baffled on what else I can do to resolve this.

EDIT:
I should also mention that the restart script is able to kill and restart the service fine when called on its own:

```
./restart.sh #typing this into the console works as expected
```

This behavior is only observed when it is called on an out of memory exception, that is, when this line is called:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./restart.sh
```

Edit2:
I've made some modifications to my restart script to try to find where it is failing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

envDeploy=`whoami`

if [ "$envDeploy" == "dev_account" ]; then
    envName=development
elif [ "$envDeploy" == "dev_account" ]
then
    envName=quality
elif [ "$envDeploy" == "prod_account" ]
then
    envName=production
fi

PID=`pgrep -f application.jar` >> check.log

echo "PID is $PID" >> check.log

netstat -nlp | grep $PID >> check.log
kill -9 $PID >> check.log
ps $PID >> check.log
netstat -nlp | grep $PID >> check.log
kill -9 $PID >> check.log
echo "checking defunct processes" >> check.log
ps -ef | grep defunct >> check.log
sleep 15
echo "===========" >> check.log
echo "checking jmx port" >> check.log
netstat -nlp | grep $PID >> check.log
netstat -nlp | grep 9010 >> check.log
kill $PID >> check.log
netstat -tupln |grep ":<Your_Port_Here>" >> check.log
sleep 5 >> check.log
jps >> check.log
echo "Restarting application for $envName environment" >> check.log
./start.sh $envName; >> check.log
```

After adding in `netstat -nlp | grep 9010 >> check.log`, I was able to see the following output from check.log:

```
PID is 11959
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11959/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11959/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11959/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38933           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11959/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36257           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11959/java
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
11959 pts/0    Zl     0:38 [java] <defunct>
checking defunct processes
sysibrt+ 13296 13287  0 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep defunct
===========
checking jmx port
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13287/sh
13370 Jps
Restarting automation-cfg-svc for qa environment
```

The process ID for port 9010 changed after the OOm error, indicating that the service had restarted.  This should not happen, as there is nothing before `./start.sh $envName;` to restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the application is not killed by the script, debug and fix this.

Comment: I'm doing that; the line "kill -9 $PID" seems to kill the service, and when I use the restart script on its own, it restarts the service as expected.  This behavior only seems to occur when it is called on OOM errors.